# script5 access is denied ie9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9

I have this error which is always displayed on IE 9, when the cursor has a busy status: `script5 access is denied on line 1 column 1` which is `<!DOCTYPE html>`

```
function busyCursor() {
if (!window["busystatus"]) {
    var busystatus = {};
}

busystatus.onStatusChange = function onStatusChange(data) {
    var status = data.status;
    if (status === "begin") { 
        document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';
        disableScreen();
    } else { 
        document.body.style.cursor = 'auto';
        $("#overlay ").remove();
    }
};

jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(busystatus.onStatusChange);

function disableScreen() {
    var div= document.createElement("div");
    div.id += "overlay";
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

I use jquery-1.11.0.min.js and jquery-ui-1.11.2.min.js.

Why do I have this error?

Thank you.